# Preferential Select Query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The issue that we are trying to tackle is best shown with the following illustrative example:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1
(
  id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  colA INT,
  colB  VARCHAR(10),
   
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);


CREATE TABLE table_2
(
  id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  colY INT,
  colZ  VARCHAR(10),
   
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);


INSERT INTO table_1(colA, colB) VALUES(1, 'NPD5A6V9EI'), (2, 'ISO4IK42YQ'), (4, 'J12QAN4O42'), (6,'V8YTZFHCU4');

INSERT INTO table_2(colY, colZ) VALUES(3, 'RBUNWLO753'), (4, 'X2BCEY7O8B'), (5, 'BNUS7R4225'), (6, '72NOWCTH5G');
```

We would like to select our result based on the value of `colA` in `table_1` but if that does not return a result , we would like to return our result based on the value of `colY` in `table_2`.  In other words SELECTing from `table_2` is the backup for SELECTing from `table_1`.  The query returns `NULL` only if neither table satisfies the condition.

A pseudo SQL query could be:

```
SELECT colB FROM table_1 where colA = 3 OR SELECT colZ FROM table_2 where colY = 3;
```

The query should return output based on the following I/O table:

```
I    O
=    =
1    NPD5A6V9EI -- From table_1
2    ISO4IK42YQ -- From table_1
3    RBUNWLO753 -- From table_2
4    J12QAN4O42 -- From table_1 (has precedence over table_2 entry) 
5    BNUS7R4225 -- From table_2
6    V8YTZFHCU4 -- From table_1 (has precedence over table_2 entry)
9    NULL
```

---

Kindly suggest solutions that:

1. make use of the latest DB features (for posterity)
2. work with MySQL version `5.6.51` (for our application)

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`. If the joined column is NULL, use the column from the other table with `COALESCE` or `IFNULL`

Comment: @Barmar left join not going to work as certain key values are missing from table A and that's when table B should kick in. Union seems to be a better way.

Comment: Please explain - where the last row of the desired output `(9, NULL)` is taken from?

Answer (score 1):

Write a subquery that generates all the `I` rows that you want.

Then left join this with the two tables, and use `IFNULL` to take the matching value from `table_1` in preference to `table_2`.

```
SELECT ids.id AS I, IFNULL(t1.colB, t2.colZ) AS O
FROM (SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 ... UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS ids
LEFT JOIN table_1 AS t1 ON t1.colA = ids.id
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON t2.colY = ids.id
ORDER BY ids.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply don't kn ow where you get your last row.

also with Myql 8 you can ise the window function ROW_NUMBER

the rest is self explantory, the sorting comes from colA and Col1, when there are teh same numbers the second column orderby2 comes and sorts first for the first table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_1
> (
>   id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   colA INT,
>   colB  VARCHAR(10),
>    
>   PRIMARY KEY(id)
> );
>
>
> CREATE TABLE table_2
> (
>   id  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   colY INT,
>   colZ  VARCHAR(10),
>    
>   PRIMARY KEY(id)
> );
>
>
> INSERT INTO table_1(colA, colB) VALUES(1, 'NPD5A6V9EI'), (2, 'ISO4IK42YQ'), (4, 'J12QAN4O42'), (6,'V8YTZFHCU4');
>
> INSERT INTO table_2(colY, colZ) VALUES(3, 'RBUNWLO753'), (4, 'X2BCEY7O8B'), (5, 'BNUS7R4225'), (6, '72NOWCTH5G');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @i := @i +1 AS I,
> colB AS O
> FROM
> (SELECT colA as orderby1,colB,1 ordberby2 froM table_1 
> UNION 
> SELECT colY, colZ,2 froM table_2 ) t1,(SELECT @i := 0) t2
> ORDER BY orderby1,ordberby2
> ```
>
> ```
>  I | O         
> -: | :---------
>  1 | NPD5A6V9EI
>  2 | ISO4IK42YQ
>  3 | RBUNWLO753
>  4 | J12QAN4O42
>  5 | X2BCEY7O8B
>  6 | BNUS7R4225
>  7 | V8YTZFHCU4
>  8 | 72NOWCTH5G
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=8c98581f8f6cbc273613f990be91d492)*